# how to load a picture from .js file to html?

Tags: javascript

I have a file called src.js which has all the scripts for my html page.

now on my html page I am using this :

```
<script language="javascript" src="src.js">
</script>
```

to call the .js file to use it.
I am not sure how to set up the images links in the .js file or how to call them in the .html file 
I need a simple answer please :)

Comment: The `language` attribute is deprecated, use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: If the images are going to be loaded statically, you could embed them in HTML without using JavaScript.

Comment: is there any way that I can set up variable for each img link ?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz I have 20 pages using 3 different images, and I have to change the image every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a placeholder for your images in the HTML otherwise you would need to dynamically modify the HTML DOM structure.

As for using variables for image links, refer to the code below which pre-loads the images.

```
if (document.images)
{
  preload_image_object = new Image();
  // set image url
  image_url = new Array();
  image_url[0] = "http://mydomain.com/image0.gif";
  image_url[1] = "http://mydomain.com/image1.gif";
  image_url[2] = "http://mydomain.com/image2.gif";
  image_url[3] = "http://mydomain.com/image3.gif";

   var i = 0;
   for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
     preload_image_object.src = image_url[i];
}
```

The browser must have the `document.images` attribute defined.

Comment: I have 20 pages using 3 different images, and I have to change the image every day :)

Comment: Why don't you use the same url for the images so that when you replace one in the server, the new one shows up?

Comment: all I want to do is to store the image url in a var then use that var in my html file. That is all

Comment: I want to keep the old images for the older posts.

Comment: Ok, I guess you would be editing the .js file. In that case, the answer I gave above still satisfies your requirements. You can see how an array is created and how to .src attribute is assigned. However, if you want to preserve older image links, you may need to change your design approach.

Comment: i tried to make an array with the links of images, then I tried to call then inside the html, but when I run it it did not work.

Comment: You can't call them inside HTML, you have to do this on some JavaScript event code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="_images"></div>
<script>
var images = {  // images with properties
    image1 : {url:'http://image1',property:'value'},
    image2 : {url:'http://image2',props:[],else:'val'}
}
for(var i in images){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = images[i].url;
    // put image anywhere you want
    document.getElementById('_images').appendChild(image)
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me which one to put in the .js file and how I use the image in the html ?

Comment: images container:<div id="_images"></div>   script: document.getElementById('_images').appendChild(image)

Comment: then what you want? @Maansahir